# Как добиться плавности анимации

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть несколько скрытых блоков *(как с темами на форуме)*. При клике мы их открываем. При клике на вторую/третью... открываем её и закрываем предыдущую *(пример будет в конце)* все действие через чур дергается или слишком скачет по экрану.

Сама проблема в гиф:

[image: Сама проблема в гиф]

[А вот ссылка для теста онлайн](http://sheenv.github.io/stackov/)

А вот и сам скрипт:

```
$(function(){
    //open-post
    $('.wi_head').click(function(){
        $('.wi_body').slideUp(500).removeClass('active');
        $(this).next('div').filter(function(){
            return $(this).css('display')=='block'
        }).slideUp(500);
        $(this).next('div').filter(function(){
            return $(this).css('display')=='none'
        }).slideDown(500, function(){
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).parent('.wall_item').offset().top - 43}, 1);
        }).prev('div').addClass('active');
        return false;
    })
});
```

Хотел бы узнать, может можно решить вот это дерганье хоть как–то?

Comment: судя по всему вы говорите про часть `$('html, body').animate({...},1)` так как у параметра duration установлено маленькое значение, кажется что происходит скачок, попробуйте увеличить его до 500 например

Comment: Видно я описал проблему не так
вся проблема в том 
что сначала элементы уезжают в верх , а потом вниз
и это и есть "дерганье". 
я хочу узнать можно ли это побороть.
В варианте если сначала открывать новость , в уже после закрывать
проблема исчезает но появляется другая.
с scrollTop: они сбивается полностью. а это совсем не то что мне нужно.

Answer (score 2):

При использовании .slideUp() и .slideDown() анимация может дёргаться, если не указана высота разворачиваемого/сворачиваемого блока.

Comment: высчитать размер блока который будет открываться и закрываться нельзя, так как он будет иметь разный размер всегда, ведь он наполнены будет разным содержимым. Разве что на лету. если это возможно.